# Laravel Log-in Error

Tags: authentication, laravel-4

I Developing a laravel application with login credents.

but i getting error while loggin.

here is my controller file.

```
public function check_login()
{
    $credents=array('username'=>Input::get('username'),'password'=>Input::get('password'));
    if(Auth::attempt($credents))
    {

        echo "Success";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Sorry,";
    }
}
```

and my auth.php file.

```
 'driver' => 'eloquent',

 'model' => 'User',

 'table' => 'users',

 'reminder' => array(

    'email' => 'emails.auth.reminder',

    'table' => 'password_reminders',

    'expire' => 60,

),
```

getting username, password from a form. 
the loggin error is working good. but doest not showing login success. my password in md5 format.

anybody please give a good solution. thanks

Comment: What error are you getting? I'd guess the issue is that you're using an MD5. Why not just use `Hash::make()`?

Comment: ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)

Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials() must be an instance of Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface, instance of User given, called in F:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Guard.php on line 371 and defined

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post your model, but if you're using a custom User model, you'll need to implement `UserInterface` and `RemindableInterface` as the [default User model](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/models/User.php) does.